# React single component on different pages ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, razor, reactjs, react-router

I'm new to Reactjs. I'm not using currently any transpiler like Babel nor I'm using a build system like Webpack. I'm on Visual Studio and using Web Compiler extension to compile JSX into JS. Here is my code at the `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
   <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/css/site.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="root">
      @RenderBody()
   </div>
   <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="~/lib/react/react.js"></script>
   <script src="~/lib/react/react-dom.js"></script>
   <script src="~/js/jsx.min.js"></script> <!--Here is my react compiled JSX file-->
  </body>
```

And in this file, I'm using 2 components:

```
var MainComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return <div id="Mainaccordion" className="panel-group" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                <Level1Component title=".NET Core" parentAccordion="Mainaccordion" collapseTarget="dotnet" heading="dotnet">
            ...............
            ...............
            ...............
            </div>;
    }
});

var AccordionComponent = React.createClass({
   render: function () {
      return <div><h2>Hello</h2></div>
   }
});

ReactDOM.render(<MainComponent />, document.getElementById('accordionexample'));
```

I've 2 pages, one is Index.cshtml where I'm displaying `<MainComponent />` and another page Try.cshtml where I want to use `<AccordionComponent />`. But when I try to navigate to `Try.cshtml`, I get the error `target container is not a dom element` in the browser???

Where I'm doing something wrong? Should I use React Router? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an element with id='accordionexample' in all the HTML pages where the React component is loaded. e.g. `<div id="accordionexample"></div>`.

Comment: What if I want to load one component in one page and second component on another page if I use `<div id="accordionexample"></div>` on both pages? how should I do that?

Comment: In that case you should call ReactDOM.render(...). with different parameters in different pages, or to call it only if the div element exists in the current page.

Comment: How can I do that can you please modify your code and show the practical example if possible? I think different parameters and rendering different components based-upon the parameters look fine. Can you please show an example or provide a link to?